# How to parse XML string with multiple identical fields and nested data using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, string, elementtree

I am fetching XML data from a server, storing it in a string, which contains several fields with the same name and also nested data. How do I parse this correctly? Here is a sample of what it could look like.

```
 <Product>
     <ProductNumber>14432</ProductNumber>
     <CreationDate>2019</CreationDate>
     <ProductVersion>
        <Config>A</Config>
        <Design>1</Design>
        <DesignCreated>2018</DesignCreated>
        <DesignedBy>Jon</DesignedBy>
        <Design>2</Design>
        <DesignCreated>2019</DesignCreated>
        <DesignedBy>Doe</DesignedBy>
     </ProductVersion>
 </Product>
```

What I am doing so far is

```
    import ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.fromstring(content_string))
```

The problem here is that I can not access any of the data inside ProductVersion doing this. When I call

```
  tree.find('ProductVersion')
```

I get

```
   attrib: {}
   tag 'ProductVersion'
   tail: None
   text: None
```

So what I have done so far is

```
    product_version_start = str(content_string).find("<ProductVersion>")-2
    product_version_end = str(content_string).find("</ProductVersion>")+15
```

To locate the substring within my XML string and create a new tree from this.

```
    tree_productVersion = ET.fromstring(content_string[product_version_start:product_version_end])
```

But now when I try

```
    tree_productversion.find('Design').text
```

only the first field is returned. I want to access all the fields and get all information.

So therefore I have two questions, is there a better way to parse the nested data? And how do I parse all fields when they have the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the children of `<ProductVersion>`.

```
pv = tree.find('ProductVersion') 
for child in pv:
    print(child.text)
```

Output:

```
A
1
2018
Jon
2
2019
Doe
```